# Edit text validations in fragments android

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment, fragmenttransaction

In my app, I have navigation drawer in main activity with 3 fragments. if I click each item in menu,the fragment is loaded. here each fragment having many edit text. in second fragment ,I am submitting the form (first fragment values +second fragment fields). how to validate the first fragment edit text with set error.

I cannot set set error after fragment transaction to first fragment. am I doing anything wrong.

code for fragment as below

```
FpcDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new FpcDetailsFragment();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detailsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            MainActivity.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every submittion set proper validation on button click like below:

```
 btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    View focusView = null;
                    boolean cancelLogin = false;
                    fname = edt_first_name.getText().toString();
                    lname = edt_last_name.getText().toString();
                    user_email = edt_email.getText().toString();
                    user_phn = edt_primary_contact.getText().toString();


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fname)) {
                        edt_first_name.setError(getString(R.string.userName_required));
                        focusView = edt_first_name;
                        cancelLogin = true;
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lname)) {
                        edt_last_name.setError(getString(R.string.userName_required));
                        focusView = edt_last_name;
                        cancelLogin = true;
                    }


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user_email)) {
                        edt_email.setError(getString(R.string.email_required));
                        focusView = edt_email;
                        cancelLogin = true;
                    } else if (!isValidEmail(user_email)) {
                        edt_email.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_email));
                        focusView = edt_email;
                        cancelLogin = true;
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user_phn) & !isValidPhone((user_phn))) {
                        edt_primary_contact.setError(getString(R.string.phone_required));
                        focusView = edt_primary_contact;
                        cancelLogin = true;
                    }
                    if (cancelLogin) {
                        // error in login
                        focusView.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        editProfile();
                    }

                }});
```

Create methods for chekcs:

```
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean isValidPhone(String pass) {
        return pass != null && pass.length() == 10;
    }
```

After that the values you get from first fragment send through bundles like:

```
 Fragment fr=new FpcDetailsFragment ();
 FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
 android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("username", fname+ " "+lname);
 fr.setArguments(args);
 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
 ft.commit();
```

And To receive the data do the following,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("username");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. are u meant to validate on every fragment when moving to next fragment?.. but i am validating submitting the frag1 and frag2 details in fragment 2 only. if anything wrong 1 fragment2 ,i can show error message there itself(fragment2)..if anything wrong in fragment 1, i should move to farg1 and should show the error message on particular fields. here it is not showing.

Comment: @saravanan yes you have to validate values on that particular fragment only. the code i posted will work perfectly for that purpose.

Comment: ok thanks. but the user can sequentially visiting the fragments by forward and backward. it may irritate the user everytime validating the fields. as my requirement is submit fragment1 and fragment 2 values in fragment 2 only.. is there any way?.. the problem is after reloading fragment1, i cannot set setError on a particular fields. how to just call fragment1 without reloading it. pls

Comment: @saravanan in that case you must restrict user to stay on same fragment until he completes the submittion. If you allow them to move around it will create headache for you to manage everything.

Comment: also the submittion will happen in fragment two only. you are getting and forwrding the values from fragment one only.

Comment: yes. all are working fine by submitting the data. if any field is wrongly typed, i should reload fragment ( reload is right way?..or any way to come fragment 1 ?). after reloading , i should show error message on edit text fields...this is not working. pls

Comment: @saravanan why are you reloading  firstly... just set user side validations first like i did in above code, there should no typo error like wrong format and all, after that you must set the server check for reloading, like if there is any duplicate value or any kind of error, user must traverse to that particular fragment by showing error in toast.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the nature of the information you want to validate, but you can use a Singleton class which contains the info from fragment 1 and fragment 2, and when you want to submit your form you can simply get the info from that class and validate it.

**EDIT:**

Lets say we have FragmentA, FragmentB and a Singleton DataBuilder which contains the data from the two fragments. In FragmentA you can save all your data into the DataBuilder and navigate the user to FragmentB. Then just before submitting the data you have to validate it. And if the validation for FragmentA is false, just navigate the user back to FragmentA and show a message.

**FragmentA:**

```
package aero.djetops;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

private EditText firstInput;
private EditText secondInput;
private EditText thirdInput;
private Button bContinue;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA_layout, container, false);

    firstInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_input);
    secondInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_input);
    thirdInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_input);


    // populate the inputs with the data from DataBuilder
    firstInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentA_firstInputData());
    secondInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentA_secondInputData());
    thirdInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentA_thirdInputData());

    bContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentA_firstInputData(firstInput.getText().toString());
            DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentA_secondInputData(secondInput.getText().toString());
            DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentB_thirdInputData(thirdInput.getText().toString());

            FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentB)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

}

**FragmentB:**

```
package aero.djetops;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

    private EditText firstInput;
    private EditText secondInput;
    private EditText thirdInput;
    private Button bSubmit;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentB_layout, container, false);

        firstInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_input);
        secondInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_input);
        thirdInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_input);


        // populate the inputs with the data from DataBuilder
        firstInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentB_firstInputData());
        secondInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentB_secondInputData());
        thirdInput.setText(DataBuilder.getInstance().getFragmentB_thirdInputData());

        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentB_firstInputData(firstInput.getText().toString());
                DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentB_secondInputData(secondInput.getText().toString());
                DataBuilder.getInstance().setFragmentB_thirdInputData(thirdInput.getText().toString());

                if(validateDataFragmentA()) {
                    showErrorMessage();
                    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentA)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    return;
                } else if(validateDataFragmentB()) {
                    showErrorMessage();
                    return;
                }

                // everything is ok
                // submit data here
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**DataBuilder:**

```
package aero.djetops;

public class DataBuilder {
    private static DataBuilder ourInstance = new DataBuilder();

    public static DataBuilder getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    // fragment A
    private String fragmentA_firstInputData;
    private String fragmentA_secondInputData;
    private String fragmentA_thirdInputData;


    // fragment B
    private String fragmentB_firstInputData;
    private String fragmentB_secondInputData;
    private String fragmentB_thirdInputData;


    private DataBuilder() {
        fragmentA_firstInputData = "";
        fragmentA_secondInputData = "";
        fragmentA_thirdInputData = "";
        fragmentB_firstInputData = "";
        fragmentB_secondInputData = "";
        fragmentB_thirdInputData = "";
    }


    /**
     * Clear the data in the builder
     */
    public void clearInputData() {
        fragmentA_firstInputData = "";
        fragmentA_secondInputData = "";
        fragmentA_thirdInputData = "";
        fragmentB_firstInputData = "";
        fragmentB_secondInputData = "";
        fragmentB_thirdInputData = "";
    }


    // GETTERS and SETTERS

    public String getFragmentA_firstInputData() {
        return fragmentA_firstInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentA_firstInputData(String fragmentA_firstInputData) {
        this.fragmentA_firstInputData = fragmentA_firstInputData;
    }

    public String getFragmentA_secondInputData() {
        return fragmentA_secondInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentA_secondInputData(String fragmentA_secondInputData) {
        this.fragmentA_secondInputData = fragmentA_secondInputData;
    }

    public String getFragmentA_thirdInputData() {
        return fragmentA_thirdInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentA_thirdInputData(String fragmentA_thirdInputData) {
        this.fragmentA_thirdInputData = fragmentA_thirdInputData;
    }

    public String getFragmentB_firstInputData() {
        return fragmentB_firstInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentB_firstInputData(String fragmentB_firstInputData) {
        this.fragmentB_firstInputData = fragmentB_firstInputData;
    }

    public String getFragmentB_secondInputData() {
        return fragmentB_secondInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentB_secondInputData(String fragmentB_secondInputData) {
        this.fragmentB_secondInputData = fragmentB_secondInputData;
    }

    public String getFragmentB_thirdInputData() {
        return fragmentB_thirdInputData;
    }

    public void setFragmentB_thirdInputData(String fragmentB_thirdInputData) {
        this.fragmentB_thirdInputData = fragmentB_thirdInputData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. here the validation can be done easily. if any errors on validations in fragment1 , i should go there and i cannot set setError on particular edittext field.

Comment: @saravanan, you can check the answer again. I've added an example which can be helpful I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

getView() method return current view of fragment. it will easy to access there elements

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
Context context;

Button btnChangePwd, btnDeleteAccount;
EditText evNewPwd, evConformPwd;

public SettingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SettingFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    SettingFragment fragment = new SettingFragment();
    fragment.context = context;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    evNewPwd = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.setting_et_newpwd);
    evConformPwd = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.setting_et_repeatpwd);
    btnChangePwd = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.setting_btn_changepwd);
    btnDeleteAccount = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.setting_btn_delete);

    btnChangePwd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDeleteAccount.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.setting_btn_changepwd:
                TextView tv = getView().findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                if(tv.getText().toString().equals("User"))) {
                   Toast.makeText(context,"Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                   tv.setError("error");
                }
                break;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```